# Cannot figure out how to install and use io_funcs in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

I'm currently working through someone else's code and I cannot figure out what "io_funcs" are in Python.  The import line is currently throwing an error that the packages cannot be found.  I'm currently using Python 2.7

The original import line is:

```
from io_funcs.binary_io import BinaryIOCollection
```

And it is used under the context of loading in from a binary file, for example:

```
io_funcs = BinaryIOCollection()
io_funcs.array_to_binary_file(data, file_name)
file_id = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_name))[0]
    features, frame_number = io_funcs.load_binary_file_frame(file_name, 63)
io_funcs.array_to_binary_file(gen_features, new_file_name)
```

I've searched through StackOverflow and done a lot of Googling and I can't seems to find a reference to io_funcs anywhere.

Comment: Are they using [`merlin`](https://github.com/CSTR-Edinburgh/merlin) as a dependency? It looks like `io_funcs.binary_io` is [this file](https://github.com/CSTR-Edinburgh/merlin/blob/master/src/io_funcs/binary_io.py)

Comment: That wasn't listed anywhere as a dependency, but I'll give that a shot.

Thank-you!

Comment: @PatrickHaugh that worked, thank-you so much!